# Best practice for master/detail plus category in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I got the following setup:

[image: UI Layout]

Currently, I have my state provider configured so that picking an entry from the sidebar will navigate to that particular action (e.g. sales report, A in the picture). I also got a dropdown to navigate to a particular item the action should be displayed for (imagine sales person, Y in the picture).

My question is, what is the best practice to model this with AngularJS? Should I broadcast the change (Y -> X) via `$rootscope` when another item is selected so that Sidebar's controller can then update the content (A for Y -> A for X)? Or should I maybe rebuild the dropdown model every time a different action is picked from the sidebar so that clicking an entry in the dropdown actually triggers navigation to the current action (`ui-sref=<A for X>`) for that subject? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
 ui-sref=content(A , X)
```

would be the best, I guess

or in case of js, it will be:

```
$state.go('content', {A, X})
```